# Issue with opencl on linux

Tags: c, opencl, gpu

I have a desktop with a linux and a nvidia gforce 5200. The graphics card does not support opencl programming. Hence, I installed AMD APP SDK v.2 to program opencl on the CPU. 
However, when I execute after compilation I get the following:
FATAL: Module fglrx not found.
fgrlx is the module of kernel for the ATI proprietary driver. Why is this module required?

Answer (score 1):

Fglrx is a proprietary, Linux binary-only driver for ATI graphic chips with support for 3D acceleration. You can read about it [here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Fglrx)

For installing AMD App SDK the following system requirements needs to be satisfied
http://developer.amd.com/tools/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/system-requirements-driver-compatibility/
Basically an AMD CPU as the bare minimum.

Basically you need to install ATI drivers. Here is a tutorial which talk about the procedure

```
For RPM based linux (like Fedora)
```

http://gofedora.com/how-to-install-ati-catalyst-fglrx-98-drivers-fedora-11/comment-page-1/

```
For Debian based Linux (like Ubuntu)
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/

A blog talks about how to install AMD App SDK 
http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/05/install-opencl-sdk-ubuntu/

Comment: Hang on, can you run ATI opencl on an Nvidia graphics card? Surely that doesn't work. Nvidia GForce would need NVidia drivers, no? [I'd be happy to be educated on this subject and told that I'm wrong, I just didn't think these companies got along well enough to have compatible drivers]

Comment: AMD APP SDK v.2 requires these graphics driver AMD and ATI are a same company now...

Comment: As I said my graphics card does not support opencl. Hence, I just want to use the CPU. I am assuming that installing AMD APP SDK v.2 would allow me to do so without requiring catalyst drivers.

Comment: Like Kostas, I'm a little confused as to why you need FireGL graphics drivers to use the CPU. It doesn't make much sense. So makes me think this code tries to use the graphics card to do the calculations.

Comment: AMD APP has a CPU OpenCL target, but I'm not sure you can use it if you have an nVidia graphics card. Why not just download the Intel OpenCL runtime (meant for CPU's) and be done with it? Not sure it works if you have an AMD processor, though, never tried, though I see no technical reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Intel OpenCL runtime is not suitable for development, and unfortunately intel SDK seems to be available only for 64-bit linux.